# Non-split Aut(G) $\to$ Out(G)?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-groups, outer-automorphisms

I'm looking for examples of outer automorphisms of a finite group $G$ which do not lift to automorphisms (i.e. non-split quotient map $\mathrm{Aut}(G)\to \mathrm{Out}(G)$, where $\mathrm{Out}(G) = \mathrm{Aut}(G)/\mathrm{Inn}(G)).$

I'm aware of the well-known $A_6$ (also $S_6$?) example, as explained in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_automorphism_group).  The article also mentions $PSL(2.q^2)$ for $q$ odd.

Are these the smallest examples?

Is there a complete (or at least longer) list of examples somewhere?

Comment: I think that it is usually the case ( ie apart from small exceptions) that when $E$ is an extraspecial group of order $2^{2n+1}$ and $G = E *C$ (central product, with $C$ cyclic of order $4$), then ${\rm Out}(G) \cong {\rm Sp}(2n,2)$ but ${\rm Aut }(G)$ is not a split extension of the form you want.

Comment: For $\mathbb S_6$ it splits.

Comment: I think the $S_6$ remark was in reply to the parenthetical question in my second paragraph.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: (And my previous comment was in response to a now deleted comment.)

Comment: It's hard to choose but you have to choose one answer to accept. People helped you with votes, so it can help you.

Answer (score 15):

As far I can remember, the smallest example is the dihedral group $G=D_{10}$ of order $10$.

In this case, $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is the Frobenius group of order $20$ and, since $Z(G)$ is trivial, $\mathrm{Inn}(G) \simeq G$, so $\mathrm{Out}(G)=\mathbb{Z}_2$.

It is easy to check that all elements of order $2$ in $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ are actually contained in $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$, so there is no section $\mathrm{Out}(G) \to \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ and the automorphism sequence is non-split.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer.  Hard to choose just one answer to accept.

Answer (score 13):

There is a complete description in

> A. Lucchini, F. Menegazzo, and M. Morigi, *On the existence of a complement for a finite simple group in its automorphism group*, Illinois J. Math. Volume 47, Number 1-2 (2003), 395-418. ([Project Euclid](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1258488162))

of which finite simple groups have complements in their automorphism groups.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer.  Hard to choose just one answer to accept.

Answer (score 6):

As Francesco says, the smallest example is $D_{10}$. It is a normal subgroup of the Frobenius group of order $20$ and that extension is not split, as can be seen from looking at the $2$-Sylows. There are many more small examples, here is Magma code that will produce them for you:

```
for X in SmallGroups([2..100]) do
auts:=AutomorphismGroup(X);
G:=PermutationGroup(auts);
m:=PermutationRepresentation(auts);
H:=sub<G|[a: a in G | IsInner(a@@m)]>;
if not HasComplement(G,H) then GroupName(X), GroupName(G); end if;
end for;
```

The first few lines of the output:

```
D10 G20
D16 D8:C2^2
Q16 D8:C2^2
C2*D8 C2wrC2^2
C2*Q8 C2^3:S4
C3:S3 H432
C5:C4 C2*G20
D20 C2*G20
D26 C13:C12
C3*D10 C2*G20
C8:C4 (C2^2*C4):D8
C8:C4 C2^2:(D8:C2^2)
C8:C4 C2^2:(D8:C2^2)
H32^15 D8:C2^3
OMC32 D8:C2^2
D32 D16:(C2*C4)
Q32 D16:(C2*C4)
```

Instead of a (mostly) human-readable name, you can also get a unique identifier for the groups by replacing "GroupName" by "IndentifyGroup". That will allow you to play more with these examples, by allowing you to reconstruct them later from their identifiers.

Comment: There is a command HasComplement(G,H), which you could use to simplify that test. Also your computation of H can be very slow if G is large.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer.  Hard to choose just one answer to accept.

Comment: Thanks, Derek, I could not remember what it was called.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/293438) referenced in this answer.

Answer (score 6):

A variation on Geoff's comment: Griess has proved that it's usually nonsplit for extraspecial $2$-groups:

> Robert L. Griess, Jr., *Automorphisms of extra special groups and
>   nonvanishing degree 2 cohomology*, Pacific Journal of
>   Mathematics Vol. 48, No. 2 (1973) pp 403-422 doi:[10.2140/pjm.1973.48.403](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/pjm.1973.48.403),
>   ([pdf](https://msp.org/pjm/1973/48-2/pjm-v48-n2-p09-p.pdf))

Comment: no worries, happy to help.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293436/non-split-autg-to-outg#comment728317_293436) referenced in this answer.