# Terminological question on finite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, terminology

Is there a standard term to denote finite groups $G$ with the property that the projection $\operatorname{Aut} G \to \operatorname{Out} G$ from automorphisms of $G$ to outer automorphisms is split?

Comment: The finite simple groups with this property are characterised in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-47/issue-1-2/On-the-existence-of-a-complement-for-a-finite-simple/10.1215/ijm/1258488162.full). See also [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293436/non-split-autg-to-outg), which I just noticed.

Comment: Name of the paper [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/427810/terminological-question-on-finite-groups#comment1100253_427810) by @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda:  [Lucchini, Menegazzo, and Morigi - On the existence of a complement for a finite simple group in its automorphism group](https://doi.org/10.1215/ijm/1258488162); title of the question referenced in the same comment: [Non-split Aut(G) $\to$ Out(G)?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293436/non-split-autg-to-outg)

Comment: In fact this property makes perfect sense for all groups, finite infinite.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, it appears that the is no standard name; but the paper by Lucchini, Menegazzo and Morigi is very interesting.